# How to Remove the Border of a Canvas in iText7?

Tags: c#, itext7

I want to remove the border around the canvas or the rectangle , Is there any method to do that ?

```
 PdfPage page = documentEvent.GetPage();
 PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
 iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle rectangle = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(36, 3 , 628, 777);
            
 pdfCanvas.Rectangle(rectangle);
 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, rectangle);
 Table table = new Table(2, false);
 canvas.Add(table);
```